# Can not access other OneDrive Details in MS graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access users OneDrive details for particular tenant. I have used https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drives to get drive details. But it is returning data for admin user who is generated application ID in Azure Directory.

Going forward, I need to iterate drive items (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drives/{driveId}/list/items) 
and items permission (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drives/{driveId}/list/items/{itemId}/driveItem/permissions). But i stuck at fetching drive details itself.

I have given the Application permission as,

**Files.Read.All - Read files in all site collection**

Response header i am getting,

```
**content-type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
cache-control: private
client-request-id: f612b993-7a31-4171-8feb-8f4ee1f6564b
request-id: f612b993-7a31-4171-8feb-8f4ee1f6564b**
```

Response Preview:

```
**{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": []
}**
```

Please suggest if i missing anything to get users onedrive details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One of the following permissions is required to call this API. You need to confirm you have set the **Sites.Read.All** and **Sites.ReadWrite.All**. Common admin account will be work account but not the personal Microsoft account, just Files.Read.All is not enough.

[image]